# Можно ли упростить выражение?

Tags: javascript

```
response.data !== undefined && response.data.length > 0
```

Условие должно проверять:

1. Существует ли массив "data"?
2. Есть ли в нем значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверки на undefined недостаточно. Так там может быть не массив, а любое значение, например null. Вам надо проверить, что это действительно массив и потом проверить размер.

```
var data = response.data;
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(data) == "[object Array]" && data.length > 0) {
    // data - это массив и в нем есть элементы
}
```

Comment: а можно просто убрать один знак `=`

Comment: @Grundy да. но если у объекта нет свойства length, но будет ошибка.

Comment: с чего бы это?. `undefined > 0 === false`

Comment: ну если у объекта нет length, то проверять length - это ошибка в логике  программы.

Comment: почему же? с логикой как раз все в порядке: если у объекта нет length - мы не зайдем внутрь условия - как и задумывалось

Comment: @Grundy да. вы правы.

Comment: А почему нельзя проверять что это массив вот так `Array.isArray(...)`, вместо прототипа?

Comment: @коллеги, да действительно , почему просто не проверить Array.isArray(...). Для чего делать `Object.prototype.toString.call(data) == "[object Array]"` . Или isArray имеет подводные камни?